# Converting json array value to multiple rows using json_array_elements in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a text field named `json_col` in my postgres (version 10) table.  I am trying to expand the two arrays  `MyArray` & `impressions` into multiple rows using SQL

```
select 
json_col::json -> 'content'->>'objectID' as objectID
,json_array_elements_text(json_col::json -> 'content'->'MyArray') as MyArrayValue
,json_array_elements(json_col::json -> 'content'->'impressions')->>'intent' as intent
from my_pg_table
```

sample data

```
{   "content": {
    "objectID": "ABC",
    "ObjectType": "MyType",
    "MyArray": [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ],
    "impressions": [
      {
        "intent": "Large"
      },
      {
        "intent": "Small"
      },
      {
        "intent": "Regular"
      },
      {
        "intent": "Medium"
      }
    ]   } }
```

In the output, i am getting the outer array (impressions) as expected. Also the first array (MyArray) is expanding to multiple rows, but it does'nt create row for each of the record created by the first array expansion.

i am getting output like this.

```
  objectID  intent  MyArrayValue
   
   ABC  Large   Blue
   
   ABC  Small   Black
   
   ABC  Regular [NULL]
   
   ABC  Medium  [NULL]
```

But I am looking for an output as below.

```
objectID    intent  MyArrayValue

ABC Large   Blue

ABC Large   Black

ABC Small   Blue

ABC Small   Black

ABC Regular Blue

ABC Regular Black

ABC Medium  Blue

ABC Medium  Black
```

Please let me know if you have any input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it in this way:

```
with cte as (
select 
json_col::json -> 'content'->>'objectID' as objectID
,json_array_elements(json_col::json -> 'content'->'impressions')->>'intent' as intent
from my_pg_table 
),
cte1 as 
(
select 
json_col::json -> 'content'->>'objectID' as objectID
,json_array_elements_text(json_col::json -> 'content'->'MyArray') as MyArrayValue
from my_pg_table
)

select 
t1.objectID,t1.intent,t2.myarrayvalue
from cte t1 inner join cte1 t2 on t1.objectID=t2.objectID
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f6f8783b6c009e0a21a7a29d57ea6c12)

Comment: Thank you @Akhilesh.

I have an approach as follows as well, somehow i m not able to apply it on top the select statement.   I will go ahead with the join approach.

select a,b from unnest(array[1,2]) a, lateral unnest(array[1,2,3]) b;

Answer (score 1):

Use the function in lateral joins:

```
select 
    json_col::json -> 'content'->>'objectID' as objectID,
    impressions->>'intent' as intent,
    MyArrayValue
from my_pg_table
cross join json_array_elements(json_col::json -> 'content'->'impressions') as impressions
cross join json_array_elements_text(json_col::json -> 'content'->'MyArray') as MyArrayValue
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a1e81fdb5f77313e1823e17db904f128)

Comment: thank you @klin ,  i have an approach as follows as well, somehow i m not able to apply it on top the select statement.   I will go ahead with the join approach.

select a,b from unnest(array[1,2]) a, lateral unnest(array[1,2,3]) b;